# Excel VBA Run-time error 1004 when inserting or value formula into cell

Tags: vba, excel

I got the run-time 1004 error when It try to insert a formula into a cell

```
Range("B64").Value = "=INDEX(AK7:AK123;G74;1)"

//I also tried
Range("B64").Formula = "=INDEX(AK7:AK123;G74;1)"
//And
Range("B64").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(AK7:AK123;G74;1)"
```

But this gives the error. If I try inserting a number or a regular string like `"test"` it does work, but like this it doesn't. Im new to VBA and im wondering why this would give a problem since it would never in languages im used to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inserting a formula with VBA requires that you use EN-US standards like,

```
Range("B64").Formula = "=INDEX(AK7:AK123, G74, 1)"
```

... or use the regional formula attribute like,

```
Range("B64").FormulaLocal = "=INDEX(AK7:AK123; G74; 1)"
```

You may have to also change **INDEX** to the regional equivalent. The latter is necessary when you have a system with regional settings that do not use the EN-US standard of a comma for a *list separator*.

see [Range.FormulaLocal Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851(v=office.15).aspx) for more information.