# 1004 error when writing a formula to a cell using VBA-Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to write a formula into a cell, using VBA. The code excerpt  below delivers the correct formula, with correct references. But I keep getting a   1004 run-time error. I can't figure out what is triggering it.  Hope this code excerpt is  enough to reveal the answer, but if you need more just ask.

```
 Set rg_sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RUNGLANCE")
  for colNo = 2 to 8
   for rowNo = 3 to 27
     daySheetName = Cells(1,colNo)
     rg_sheet.cells(rowNo,ColNo).formula = "=VLookUp(" & Chr(34) & "$A" & rowNo & Chr(34) & "), " & daySheetName & "!(" & chr(34) & "$A$3:$B$27" & Chr(34) & ", 2, False"
   next rowNo
  next colNo
```

Comment: this fixed it for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557438/excel-vba-run-time-error-1004-when-inserting-or-value-formula-into-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
rg_sheet.cells(rowNo,ColNo).formula = "=VLookUp(" & Chr(34) & "$A" & rowNo & Chr(34) & "), " & daySheetName & "!(" & chr(34) & "$A$3:$B$27" & Chr(34) & ", 2, False"
```

try

```
rg_sheet.Cells(rowNo, colNo).Formula = "=VLookUp($A" & rowNo & ", " & daySheetName & "!" & "$A$3:$B$27" & ", 2, False" & ")"
```

Comment: @hlf - Issue was with placement of `"`.